# How to stop else condition from execution in SQL case statements

Tags: sql, case

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DO.Contract_Number AS Contract_Number,
    CASE 
       WHEN w3.ContractNo <> DO.Contract_Number 
          THEN 'Ambiguity in contract No'
    END AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    w3.ContractNo AS contract_number,
    CASE 
       WHEN w3.Transporter_Name <> TI.TransporterName 
          THEN 'Ambiguity in Transporter Name'
    END AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, TransporterInformation TI, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID
```

I want to remove else result from case statement after removing else it returns null.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add condition from `CASE` statement to `WHERE` and simple remove `CASE` like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DO.Contract_Number AS Contract_Number,
    'Ambiguity in contract No' AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID AND w3.ContractNo <> DO.Contract_Number 

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    w3.ContractNo AS contract_number,
    'Ambiguity in Transporter Name' AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, TransporterInformation TI, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID AND w3.Transporter_Name <> TI.TransporterName
```

**Edit**

If you are expecting multiplse `WHEN` statements for each `CASE` then you should use `OR` in `WHERE` condition like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DO.Contract_Number AS Contract_Number,
    CASE 
        WHEN conditiion1
            THEN 'value1'
        WHEN conditiion2
            THEN 'value2'
        ELSE ''
    END AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID AND (conditiion1 OR conditiion2)

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    w3.ContractNo AS contract_number,
    CASE 
        WHEN conditiion1
            THEN 'value1'
        WHEN conditiion2
            THEN 'value2'
        ELSE ''
    END AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, TransporterInformation TI, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID AND (conditiion1 OR conditiion2)
```

**Edit 2 : Use Standard JOIN Statement instead of older join syntax**

As @Gordon Linoff suggested it is better to use Standard JOIN statement over Older one. You will find several blogs or posts related to this topic,some of them are here. [SQL SERVER – Why Should You Not to Use Old Style JOIN?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/10/08/sql-server-why-should-you-not-to-use-old-style-join/) or [Using JOIN keyword or not](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78225/using-join-keyword-or-not).

I am rewriting first `SELECT` statement here for sample.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DO.Contract_Number AS Contract_Number,
    CASE 
        WHEN conditiion1
            THEN 'value1'
        WHEN conditiion2
            THEN 'value2'
        ELSE ''
    END AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3
    INNER JOIN Delivery_Order DO ON w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID 
WHERE 
    (conditiion1 OR conditiion2)
```

Comment: @karan . . . If you want upvotes, you should use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have provided answer with older join syntax because OP has already used that one. But I appreciate your comment to provide **standard** and **better** solution. I have updated my answer but if you feel it need any improvement then please edit the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@nado1122,

I see that you are using cross joins, which I am not sure is the best way to join (unless your use-case is very much specific).
However, you can avoid having the `else` part of case condition by including only the rows which qualifies your criteria. 
I believe this should solve your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DO.Contract_Number AS Contract_Number,
    'Ambiguity in contract No' AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3 JOIN Delivery_Order DO 
ON 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID
WHERE 
    w3.ContractNo <> DO.Contract_Number

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    w3.ContractNo AS contract_number,
    'Ambiguity in Transporter Name' AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, TransporterInformation TI, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID
    AND 
    w3.Transporter_Name <> TI.TransporterName;
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I'm glad I was useful for you. Cheers! 